# Reference a table with itself with cakephp 3.X

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a simple  table like this:

```
id
parent_id
title
```

I referenced the table with itself in this way:

```
ALTER TABLE categories
ADD FOREIGN KEY (category_id)
REFERENCES categories(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

bake seems to do itself the code right, but when I check my select form I don't see any available data thought the table is popolated.

What can I do? I search some answer but all are for cake 2.x

Thank's

Comment: I don't know if I can be of much help, but this type of scenario in SQL is called a "self-join". You might have better luck using that phrase when searching online, or asking the Cake developers on IRC. It would also probably help people if you posted your Model code particularly the associations.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by applying the Tree Behavior for CakePHP 3.0

Thank's